# Simple metabolic rate calculation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I've written a code to

1. Multiply 'basal metabolic rate' with the activity factor in the option select tag and provide daily calorie requirements
2. Multiply the daily calorie requirements with 0.8 to reduce calories by 20%

When i run the script in the browser it gives the below error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined

I think the problem is with the select-option tag. I'm new to js so any help would be much appreciated

HTML code

```
<form name="form2" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <p>
            <label>Input your BMR here</label>
            <input name="a">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Select your activity level</label>
            <select name="b">
                <option value="0.2" selected>No sport/exercise</option>
                <option value="0.375" >Light activity (sport/exercise 1-3 times per week)</option>
                <option value="0.55" >Moderate activity (sport/exercise 3-5 times per week)</option>
                <option value="0.725" >High activity (everyday exercise)</option>
                <option value="0.9" >Extreme activity (professional athlete)</option>
        </p>
        <input onclick=perc2() type=button value=Calculate>
        <p>
            <label>Your maintainence calories:</label>
            <input name="total1">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Calories required to lose weight</label>
            <input name="total2">
        </p>
        <input type=reset value=Reset>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
<SCRIPT>
<!--
    function perc2() {
         a = document.form2.a.value;
         b = document.form2.b.value;
         c = a*b
         d = c*0.8
         e = Math.round(c, 1)
         f = Math.round(d, 1)
         document.form2.total1.value = e
         document.form2.total2.value = f 
    }
    //-->
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/twyvsdgt/ - works in Chrome and FF and IE10. Which browser are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to get a form element in JavaScript is to use [getElementById()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementbyid.asp)

In this code for example :

```
      a = document.form2.a.value;
```

a is undefined because you are using an invalid way of getting the value.
Instead you should use:

```
a = document.getElementById("a").value;
```

EDIT: Also add an id to your input field

Comment: The element does not have an id of `a` - its the name.

Comment: and also element does not have `value()` function

Comment: @dimlucas: thank you so much for your help! its working perfectly :)  Jamiec: i use chrome, a similar script i created, worked on my page, guess i am going to correct the other script as well. Again thanks everyone for the help